# MediaPlayer plays a sound or music before calling Play() method

Tags: c#, winforms, audio, media-player, audio-player

I'm developing a game using WinForms and the MediaPlayer class to reproduce the game music and sounds (the SoundPlayer class does not reproduce two sounds simultaneously). I created a number of MediaPlayer instances into the game controller classes, one for each music or sound. For example, in the Main Menu controller constructor I have:

```
public MainMenuController(MainMenuModel mainMenuModel,
                          MainMenuView  mainMenuView)
{
        _mainMenuModel = mainMenuModel;
        _mainMenuView  = mainMenuView;

        _idleTimer = new Timer();

        _menuBackgroundMusicPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        _menuBackgroundMusicPlayer.Open(new Uri(_menuBackgroundMusicPath, UriKind.Relative));
        _menuBackgroundMusicPlayer.MediaEnded += MenuBackgroundMusicEndedEventHandler;

        _menuItemSelectionSoundPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        _menuItemSelectionSoundPlayer.Open(new Uri(_menuItemSelectionSoundPath, UriKind.Relative));

        _menuItemOpeningSoundPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        _menuItemOpeningSoundPlayer.Open(new Uri(_menuItemOpeningSoundPath, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

As you can see I open every music/sound into the constructor. The problem is that when I launch the execution of the game, some randomly selected (opened) music/sound is shortly played (perhaps less than half of a second) BEFORE I call the method Play(). When I finally call the Play() method for the first time, the reproduction continues from where it stopped at the game launch (so the first 200-400 ms are lost). In order to avoid this problem I have to mute every MediaPlayer instance on creation, then unmute it e reset the position to zero before calling Play(). Why do I have this problem? Does it have to do with my code?

**EDIT**: this is the main class of the game:

```
public static class Game
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        Model      model      = new Model();
        View       view       = new View(model);
        Controller controller = new Controller(model,
                                               view);
    }
}
```

This is where the Main Menu controller is instatiated:

```
public class Controller
{
    private readonly Model _model;
    private readonly View  _view;

    public OpeningMovieController OpeningMovieController { get; }
    public MainMenuController     MainMenuController     { get; }
    public SettingsMenuController SettingsMenuController { get; }

    public Controller(Model model,
                      View  view)
    {
        _model = model;
        _view  = view;

        OpeningMovieController = new OpeningMovieController(_model.OpeningMovieModel,
                                                            _view.OpeningMovieView);
        MainMenuController     = new MainMenuController(_model.MainMenuModel,
                                                        _view.MainMenuView);
        SettingsMenuController = new SettingsMenuController(_model.SettingsMenuModel,
                                                            _view.SettingsMenuView);

        OpeningMovieController.OpeningMovieEnded += OpeningMovieEndedEventHandler;

        MainMenuController.MaxIdleTimeElapsed               += MaxIdleTimeElapsedEventHandler;
        MainMenuController.CurrentlySelectedMenuItemOpening += CurrentlySelectedMenuItemOpeningEventHandler;

        SettingsMenuController.SettingsMenuClosed += SettingsMenuClosedEventHandler;

        OpeningMovieController.StartOpeningMovie();
    }

    private void OpeningMovieEndedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainMenuController.OpenMainMenu();
    }

    private void MaxIdleTimeElapsedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpeningMovieController.StartOpeningMovie();
    }

    private void CurrentlySelectedMenuItemOpeningEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (_model.MainMenuModel.CurrentlySelectedMenuItemID)
        {
            case 2:
                SettingsMenuController.OpenSettingsMenu();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void SettingsMenuClosedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainMenuController.OpenMainMenu();
    }
}
```

And this is the MenuBackgroundMusicEndedEventHandler declared in the Main Menu controller:

```
private void MenuBackgroundMusicEndedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _menuBackgroundMusicPlayer.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
    _menuBackgroundMusicPlayer.Play();
}
```

Comment: Could you show the main method of your project (or wherever the `MainMenuController` instance is created) and also show what is happening when the `MediaEnded` event is called by `_menuBackgroundMusicPlayer`? Is hard to say why you are expericing the sound plays with only the `MainMenuController` class.

Comment: @MarkusAnd I edited the question by showing the missing parts.